# AutoMapper IObjectMapper example

Tags: automapper

In short, has anyone got one, including how to register the custom mapper.

I'm trying to map a custom `IList<T>` implementation and am not getting very far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace the MapperRegistry.AllMappers with a new list. Here's the default:

```
    public static Func<IEnumerable<IObjectMapper>> AllMappers = () => new IObjectMapper[]
    {
        new DataReaderMapper(),
        new TypeMapMapper(TypeMapObjectMapperRegistry.AllMappers()),
        new StringMapper(),
        new FlagsEnumMapper(),
        new EnumMapper(),
        new ArrayMapper(),
        new EnumerableToDictionaryMapper(),
        new DictionaryMapper(),
        new ListSourceMapper(),
        new ReadOnlyCollectionMapper(), 
        new CollectionMapper(),
        new EnumerableMapper(),
        new AssignableMapper(),
        new TypeConverterMapper(),
        new NullableMapper()
    };
```

You'd take this Func, and replace it with something else, with this set of code as a starting point.

Not the prettiest thing in the world, but at least it's possible.

Comment: looking at the AutoMapper source would the ReadOnlyCollection mapper be a good example to go off - I'm mapping a PagedList (implements IList with a few extra properties)

Comment: I just created a helper in the end to map the underlying list. Creating the custom mapper was just not worth the effort.